# Codeigniter/PyroCMS Extending use of files

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I need to produce a few pages that will enable me to display lists of documents (.PDF)

What I want to know is there structure or the compatibility to use the file manager

Example:

I create a folder called animals and inside this folder I have a document called monkey.pdf and tiger.pdf

on the front end of my site I will have a page called articles -> This page will need to list all of the folders created in the file manager

When someone clicks the folder Animals I would like it to list all of the .pdfs within this specific category

Is this possible and could someone show me an example as I am confusing myself.

This is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a thread reply from my query on the PyroCMS fourm.

This is possible it has just not been documented yet and you need to look in the files document for how it works.